# JQuery slideDown() not pushing other content properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown

The following code slides down some content. It should push the rest of the page down to, and it does but it does not animate it. It statically jumps at the end of the animation.

```
$(window).load(function(){
                        $('.panel.autoc').effect('shake', {times:5}, 80);
                        $('.errors').slideDown(800);
                    });
```

Comment: You might want to show the HTML this is working on.

Comment: i think the problem is with the time try changing (800) to 2000 and 80 to 2000, if it works then change to the required times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are animating right after the page load you might see such behavior in most of the browsers. Try to give some delay after page loads and then slide it. Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('.panel.autoc').effect('shake', {times:5}, 80);
                        $('.errors').slideDown(800);
                    }, 200);
});
```